# Access to protected function in external swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've bought an external component composed by the MXP component and two external swf.
Obviously I haven't any source or fla file.
I've imported the component in my own project and it works fine (combined with the two external swf). Now I've debugged and decompiled one of this two external swf whith a stand alone program (SWF Decompailer) in order to find two functions I wanto to manage.
I've found their name [forceNextImage() and forcePrevImage()] and the class where they are declared.

The problem is that those functions are protected and I've the necessity to call them inside my project (the project where I've imported the components, of course). There's a way to do that? And how?

I hope I've been understandable even with my lacking english, but if not don't esitate to ask me..

Thanks in advance.

Fabrizio

Answer (score 1):

Can you subclass it, and then call it from the subclass?

Answer (score 1):

`protected` methods are callable from subclasses, so you can extend the component and expose them:

```
public class YourComponent extends Component
{

    public function nextImage():void
    {
        forceNextImage();
    }

    public function prevImage():void
    {
        forcePrevImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: With this solution I obtain this error:
**public attribute can be used inside packet only**
referred to the first line of code.May be for the reason that the class is in the external swf and not in the main component?

Comment: @RobertoMitriani Did you wrap the class in a `package`?